# How to find all nodes which linked by edge with exact property in OrientDB?

Tags: graph-databases, orientdb

I have several services and would like to see how they linked via requests

So I created edges as class "Http" and added property "request"

[All services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qurx0.png)

I have 4 services

1. Gateway
2. ServiceA
3. ServiceB
4. ServiceC

I would like to display all services which linked by edge with property equal "get_user_info"

> Gateway -> ServiceA -> ServiceC -> ServiceB

[What I would like to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Gmde.png)

And property equal "delete_user"

> Gateway -> ServiceB

[What I would like to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/do7b1.png)

It can be like that "SELECT * FROM Services WHERE edge.request ='get_user_info'"

I tried

```
SELECT * 
FROM Services 
WHERE in('http').request = 'get_user_info' OR out('http').request = 'get_user_info'
```

```
SELECT expand(in('http')[request='get_user_info']) FROM Services;
```

But it does not work

I tried

```
select * from `Services` WHERE @rid IN (select in from `http` where request = 'get_user_info') OR @rid IN (select out from `http` where request = 'get_user_info')
```

and it works, but I see Link from ServiceB to Gateway
Can I filter that link?

Answer (score 0):

still using OrientDB? I suggest to upgrade to ArcadeDB.

used your case as test-case for the ruby-interface to ArcadeDB (https://github.com/topofocus/arcadedb)

Basically, use a match statement. Its compiled at the bottom of the test-case.

```rb
RSpec.describe Arcade::Base do
  before(:all) do
    connect
    db = Arcade::Init.db
    My::V1.create_type
    My::E1.create_type
    db.begin_transaction
    My::V1.delete all: true
    g,a,b,c = ["Gateway", "ServiceA", "ServiceB", "ServiceC"].map {|y| My::V1.insert a: y}
    request='get_user_info'
    g.assign via: My::E1, to: a, request: request  #  create edges
    g.assign via: My::E1, to: b, request: "delete_user"
    a.assign via: My::E1, to: c, request: request
    c.assign via: My::E1, to: b, request: request

  end
  after(:all) do
     db = Arcade::Init.db
     db.rollback
  end

  context "check setup" do

    Given( :gateway  ){ My::V1.find a: 'Gateway' }
    Then { gateway.out.size == 2 }
    When( :deleted_service ){ My::V1.where a: 'ServiceB' }
    When( :request_service ){ My::V1.where a: 'ServiceA' }
    Then { gateway.nodes( :outE, where: { request: "delete_user" }) == deleted_service }
    Then { gateway.nodes( :outE, where: { request: "get_user_info" }) == request_service }

  end

  context "get deleted User relation" do
    Given( :gateway_record ){ Arcade::Match.new type: My::V1, where:{ a: 'Gateway' }, as: :g }
    Given( :gateway  ){ My::V1.where a: 'Gateway' }
    Given( :deleted_service ){ My::V1.where a: 'ServiceB' }
    Then  { gateway_record.to_s == "MATCH { type: my_v1, where: ( a='Gateway' ), as: g } RETURN g " }
    Then  { gateway_record.execute.select_result ==  gateway}

    Given( :deleted_user_record  ){ gateway_record.outE( My::E1,  where: { request: 'delete_user' }).node(as: :f) }
    Then { deleted_user_record.to_s == "MATCH { type: my_v1, where: ( a='Gateway' ), as: g }.outE('my_e1'){ where: ( request='delete_user' ) }.inV(){ as: f } RETURN g,f " }
    Then { deleted_user_record.execute.allocate_model  ==   gateway + deleted_service }
  end

end
```